# If $v_n \to 0$ in $L^2$, does $v_n \to 0$ in $L^8$?

Tags: functional-analysis, integration

If $v_n \to 0$ in $L^2$, does $v_n \to 0$ in $L^8$? Suppose the domain is a compact surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For example it could be a sphere.

Comment: Are you talking about a bounded domain in $\mathbb R^n$ with Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yeah a bounded compact domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, it can be a surface for example. I assume the measure is the usual Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I presume you are speaking of sequences $(v_n)$?

Comment: @maximumtag That would be some good information to add to your original post...

Comment: $L^2$ is not a subset of $L^8$ in that case.  Consider, on $[0,1]$, $v_n=n\chi_{[0,1/n^4]}$.  The converse can be proven for bounded domains using Hölder's inequality.

Comment: @DavidMitra You're right, I was very careless. Sorry all. I edited the post.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks. Is it ever true with Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @maximumtag:  The only thing that matters about the interval $[0,1/n^4]$ in that example is its measure.  You can generalize to other domains.